# How to determine the right motor to rotate things?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

Me and my teammates are trying to produce a motorized rotating bench. we want to rotate the bench to the other side if one of them get wet by the rain. we are currently doing the proposal for our course project. to do so, we must identify the material that must be chose. we will be using mild/stainless steel.We want to  use a shaft that will be connected by a chain link to the motor.
the question is, **how do i find the right motor that is needed for us to rotate the bench ?(only the sitting part) is there any calculation formula or else ?**

Comment: This seems like more of an engineering question than a physics question. Have you looked at the [Engineering SE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/) to see if any similar questions have been asked?